# getModelInfo with caret: what's all this stuff mean exactly?

Tags: r, r-caret

I love `caret` and diving into the inner workings of all the different models in it. I was trying to look at the underlying mechanics under the hood for some models and wasn't totally sure what some of this stuff meant, though. If I do a:

```
library(caret)
getModelInfo("xgbTree")
```

I get a lot of output, most of which is pretty obvious at face value. I know what some of these are, but can someone fill me in on the blanks? I've tried the documentation, but maybe I didn't look hard enough for where these terms are strictly defined?

- Label: name of the model, obviously
- Library: necessary libraries needed to run it
- Type: classification, regression, or both
- Parameters: tunings specific to the model
- Grid: I'm guessing this is how caret does a grid search by default?
- Loop: ?
- Fit: ?
- Predict: I'm guessing this is the way the specific model is used with a predict() function?
- Prob: ?
- Predictors: ? (this seems like it's just calling the predictor values used in the formula)
- varImp: calculating the variable importance for the features (specific to this tree algorithm no doubt)
- levels: ?
- tags: what the model is used for
- sort: ?

Do I have most of these right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all documented [here](https://topepo.github.io/caret/using-your-own-model-in-train.html). If you have any specific questions of "why"/"what-the?" just email the package maintainer (=me) or post a question on the GitHub issues page.